# Sigma-Algebra Created by Intervals

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\{x_i \}$ be a finite collection of numbers with $x_0=0< x_1< \ldots < x_n < x_{n+ 1}= 1$. Let $F$ be a sigma-algebra generated by the intervals $[x_0,x_1),[x_1,x_2),\ldots ,[x_n,1]$.

Here are the two questions I am needing help with how to start them:

1. Which functions $X:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ are measurable with respect to $F$.
2. Let $P(I)$ as the length of $I$ in $F$. Write an expression for $E[X]$ for a random variable defined on this space when the probability measure is given as the extension, $P^*$ or $P$.

Please, just help me to get started!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A function $X$ is measurable if the preimage of any interval of $\Bbb R$ lies in $F$, i.e. is the union of some of the pregiven intervals. Show that such a function must be *constant* on each $[x_i,x_{i+1})$.
2. This is basically the *discrete* distribution with $n+1$ possibile outcomes, the $i$th event has probability $p_i=x_{i+1}-x_i$.